# python, requests, lxml: simulate tab change on css grid

Tags: python, xpath, web-scraping, python-requests, lxml

I'm working with requests and lxml to scrape data from thesaurus.com

Take this url for example: https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/mass

I can get what I want with this code:

```
  url = 'https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/' + 'mass'
  r = requests.get(url)
  tree = lxml.html.fromstring(r.content)
  raw_syn_list = tree.xpath('//h2[text()="other words for "]/following-sibling::ul//text()')
```

But I can not figure out how to access the second sense of mass programmatically. It is organized on the site as another tab above the synonym grid.

[image of the tabs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SRuWH.png)

When you click a tab on the site, the relevant html element is replaced. I'm guessing that's happening in a javascript function somewhere, but I can't seem to find it.

Comment: If I understand you correctly: You want to scrape the words out of the second tab under _bulk, measurement_?

Comment: That's right. The html doc returned from requests.get(url) only contains the words from the first tab. So I'm trying to figure out how to simulate a tab change or access them in some other fashion.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the behavior in browser Developer Tools, the entire page reloads. Once the tab is clicked, re-run the code that loads the definitions treating it as a new page and don't reuse your previous webelement instances. In the example code above,

- click tab
- redo everything from requests.getUrl() on down, with different variable names
  That should get you the new content.